# PHP can't find php.ini configuration file

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4, php-ini, apache-config

I am running a webserver with Apache2.4 and have added the following lines in the httpd configuration file to setup php with Apache:

```
# PHP8 module
PHPIniDir "c:/php"
LoadModule php_module "c:/php/php8apache2_4.dll"
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I have both php and Apache extracted to their respective folders directly under my `c:/` drive and have setup the windows PATH variable for php.

Output from `phpinfo()`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  no value
Loaded Configuration File          (none)
```

**EDIT**: On Windows `php.ini` does not exist and must be created by copying either `php-ini-development` or `php-ini-production` (or re-naming either file to `php.ini`) however this did not solve the issue

Comment: Find your `php` executable and run `./php --ini`.  It will show you where the ini file is, as far as the executable knows.  `./php -i` iwll show you a LOT of information as to how it was built.

Comment: navigated to php execuatble and `php --ini` shows (none) for all php.ini paths

Comment: Some ideas: https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.phpini, -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.findphpini -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php